# WebSockets Server .NET Core - IsWebSocketRequest always returns false

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, kestrel

I'm using what I consider some fairly "standard" code in .NET Core to implement a web socket server:

```
if (ctx.Request.Path == "/api/v1/sometest")
    {
        if (ctx.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            WebSocket wsSock = await ctx.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
```

But I can never establish a session because IsWebSocketRequest is always null.

I can see the Connection: Upgrade and Upgrade: websocket headers...

I know I must be missing something but unsure what...  Scanned through github dotnet source code to see if I could figure it out that way but no luck finding a solution yet.

I'm using Windows 10
Kestrel
VS Code
.NET Core 3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had AddWebSockets in Startup.ConfigureServices BUT I forgot to also include the middleware in Startup.Configure.  Call app.UseWebSockets here to register the middleware in your chain.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/21701) app.UseWebSockets() should be placed right before app.UseEndpoints() in startup.cs .